# Scheduled script does not redirect output to file

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2012-r2

I've two similar PowerShell scripts to backup files (first purges a network drive, second does actual backup) configured to run daily in the same Windows scheduler task (just different actions):

```
Action: Start a program
Program/script: powershell.exe
Add arguments (optional): -command C:\Webs\Scripts\purgar-backups-dinahosting.ps1 > C:\Webs\Scripts\purgar-backups-dinahosting.log 2>&1

Action: Start a program
Program/script: powershell.exe
Add arguments (optional): -command C:\Webs\Scripts\backup-dynahosting.ps1 > C:\Webs\Scripts\backup-dynahosting.log 2>&1
```

I get the expected log files but the first one is always empty (0 bytes). I do get actual output if I simply run the command from command prompt:

```
powershell.exe -command C:\Webs\Scripts\purgar-backups-dinahosting.ps1 > C:\Webs\Scripts\purgar-backups-dinahosting.log 2>&1
```

... with the only peculiarity that it uses **Unix line feeds** (:-!). Given that:

1. Both scripts are saved with Windows line feeds
2. Both scripts generate output with `Write-Host`

What can explain those oddities in the first script<sup>1</sup>?

(<sup>1</sup>) Here's the code:

```
$LetraUnidad = "X:"

$RecursoNFS = "xxx_removed_xxx.dinaserver.com:/usr/containers/xxx_removed_xxx"

$EspacioContratado = "xxx_removed_xxx"

$LimitePorcentaje = "xxx_removed_xxx"



Write-Host "Verificando si ya está montada la unidad de red en $LetraUnidad..."
$UnidadRed = New-Object System.IO.DriveInfo($LetraUnidad)
if ($UnidadRed.IsReady)
{
    Write-Host "Unidad de red disponible"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Unidad de red no disponible, montando unidad..."
    net use $LetraUnidad $RecursoNFS

    if ($UnidadRed.IsReady)
    {
        Write-Host "Unidad de red disponible"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Se ha producido un error al intentar montar la unidad de red"
        exit
    }    
}



Write-Host "Obteniendo datos de espacio de la unidad $LetraUnidad..."

$EspacioOcupado = ((Get-ChildItem $LetraUnidad -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum) /1gb
$EspacioLibre = $EspacioContratado-$EspacioOcupado
$PorcentajeEspacioOcupado = ($EspacioOcupado*100/$EspacioContratado)


Write-Host "Espacio total:        " ([System.Math]::Round($EspacioContratado, 2)) " GB"
Write-Host "Espacio libre:        " ([System.Math]::Round($EspacioLibre, 2)) " GB"
Write-Host "Espacio ocupado:      " ([System.Math]::Round($EspacioOcupado, 2)) " GB"
Write-Host "Porcentaje ocupación: " ([System.Math]::Round($PorcentajeEspacioOcupado, 2))"%"
Write-Host

Write-Host "Comprobando si es necesario eliminar archivos..."
if($PorcentajeEspacioOcupado -gt $LimitePorcentaje)
{
    Write-Host "Poco espacio disponible, eliminando archivos..."
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Espacio disponible suficiente, no es necesario eliminar archivos"
    exit
}



foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -path X: | where-object{-not $_.PSIsContainer} | sort -property LastWriteTime)
{
    Write-Host "Eliminando " $file.FullName
    del $file.FullName

    $EspacioOcupado = ((Get-ChildItem $LetraUnidad -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum) /1gb
    $EspacioLibre = $EspacioContratado-$EspacioOcupado
    $PorcentajeEspacioOcupado = ($EspacioOcupado*100/$EspacioContratado)

    if($PorcentajeEspacioOcupado -lt $LimitePorcentaje)
    {
        Write-Host
        exit
    }
}
```

Comment: CMD interpret `>` and `2>&1` as redirection operators and process them by itself and does not pass them to PowerShell. Task scheduler interpret arguments as literal string. So that, `>` and `2>&1` will be passed to PowerShell and will be processed by PowerShell. And PowerShell knows, that host stream should not be redirected by `>` operator.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for the heads up. I never really understood why or when I need to split my actions in three (tiny) text boxes; those settings were actually the result of some Google scavenger hunt. What'd be the right way to run a *.ps1 and send its output to a file?

Comment: One way, which does not require you to modify scripts would be: *program:* `cmd` and *arguments:* `/c powershell -command C:\Webs\Scripts\backup-dynahosting.ps1 > C:\Webs\Scripts\backup-dynahosting.log 2>&1`.

Comment: @user4003407 this works and nothing else does for me... need to point out that it should be -file to run the ps1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Write-Host
```

may not the right Tool for the Job.
Since it is designed to directly write output to a user console (the script host) without actually producing output, e.g. to redirect or pipeline.

It is very useful for writing debug-, report- or progress-output you don't want to see in a log but only in an interactive session.
Or for messages from inside functions, that should not "return" that message

Try to use

```
Write-Output
```

for everything you want your script to output. Be careful from inside functions.

http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

Comment: That was it! No idea about why the other script did generate a proper log file but to be honest I don't care :)

Comment: '>' tells the script host to redirect the script's output. it is not part of the script itself. i can imagine that when you run the script with different hosts (powershell.exe vs the windows sheduler) the redirection is done differently. But Whatever it was, it seems to work now. Would appreciate you flagging my answer as verified :)

Comment: Oh and to awnser the question in your comment above:
Try to use `Start-Transcript -Append -Path $logFile `.

Comment: This is getting crazier... I've replaced `Write-Host` with `Write-Output`  in the *other*  script (the one which was working) and now my scheduled task gets stalled running forever and doing no real job... I guess I'll just make the change in only one script and move along.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean with `Start-Transcript -Append -Path $logFile` exactly? Task scheduler has three different input boxes for each task :-!

Comment: `Start-Transcript` is a cmdlet you can use inside your script file. It will write a copy of the script output to the provided `$logFile`. Use it inside your script like
`Start-Transcript ...; foreach($file in ...) {  Write-Host "Eliminando " $file.FullName;  del $file.FullName; }; Stop-Transcript`

Comment: Beware of `Write-Host` and `Write-Output`, though. when you use `Write-Output` inside a function, the function will "return" that output. use it in a pipeline command, it will put that value into the pipeline. `Write-Host` will circumvent all that and put anything directly to the console. But you can't log that in every situation... Try to experiment with `Write-Debug "whatever" -Debug`, but look up `'$DebugPreference  = 'Continue''` before you do.